# How to find the first intersection point of 2 systems of symbolic equations?

Tags: calculus, geometry, surfaces, parametric, intersection-theory

Hopefully this is not a fail. But, before I explain the math, I think it will be easier if I give a background of what I'm trying to do...

Imagine 2 line segments randomly defined in a $2D$ room. The line segments are 2D... Both are given a speed $v$ and $\omega$ (angular velocity). The point of the math, is to find the exact future time $t \gt 0$ where the first collision will occur.

---

The motion of the line in space-time might be considered as a parametric surface (space-time for a $1d$ object, so it is $2d$.)

**The math of the lines are:**

**Line1 X Output:** $u_1 \sin(\omega_1 \ t) +  \ v_{1x} \ t+ x_{01} $

**Line1 Y Output:** $u_1 \cos(\omega_1 \ t) + \ v_{1y}  \ t+ y_{01} $

and

**Line2 X Output:** $ u_2 \ \sin(\omega_2 t) + v_{2x} t  + {x_{02}}$

**Line2 Y Output:** $ u_2 \ \cos(\omega_2 t) + v_{2 y} t + {y_{02}}$

---

*You can consider $\omega_1,\omega_2,v_1,v_2,,x_0, y_0$, as  "unchanging" or "constant" variables, in the context of this mathematics. t is time that increments over time, u is the span(breadth) of the line, limited to a<u<b. [a,b] are constants that can be arbitrarily defined in the same way of $\omega_1,\omega_2, v_1 \dots $ etc.*

---

**What I've tried so far:**

I've reformulated some of the variable names to solve for $t_1, t_2$ like this:

$u_1 \ \sin(\omega_1 t_1) + v_{1x} \ t_1  + x_{01} = u_2  \ \sin(\omega_2 t_2) + v_{2x} t_2 + x_{02}$

$ u_1 \ \cos(\omega_1 t_1) +  v_{1y} \ t_1 + y_{01} = u_2 \ \cos(\omega_2 t_2) + v_{2y} \ t_2  + y_{02} $

**Where do I go from here?**

---

My question is this mathematically impossible, or can this be done? If so, how? My other question is, have I gotten all of my math terminology correct? If I don't have the right math terminology then its harder to find help on search engines.

Comment: Since you're looking for a collision, then $t_1 = t_2$.  I've taken the liberty to edit your question, to put in math style.

Comment: I didn't see a LateX button to make it into math text. Anyway, t1 and t2 must be different variables, because if parametric equations cannot be solved by having 1 t variable. Example here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1719286/points-of-intersection-of-two-parametric-curves

Comment: I've updated the question again to make it $t_1$ and $t_2$.   You can see how the math is written by clicking on Edit underneath the question, it will open a window with the question with the formatting text included.  This is how you learn how to format your math.    After you're done, click on Cancel to leave the question unchanged.

Comment: ok, ty. what software or website do you recommend to automatically change the text into math?

Comment: I don't know of any such software.  You have to format the math expressions yourself.